# Utilizar onemouseover

Tags: javascript, html

estoy haciendo una pagina web, y basicamente mi pregunta es como le puedo hacer para usar la funcion onemouseover de java script, quiero que al suceder el evento se despliege un menu, actualmente estoy utilizando el evento de al darle  clik, pero no se como remplazarla, aqui les dejo mi codigo de java, si ocupan mas informacion diganmelo, puse tambien el codigo de html y css por si alguien lo ocupa o quiere verlo, creo que ya deje bastante claro mi duda y esto me dice que escriba mas detalles, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.

CODIGO HTML

```
<nav class="main-nav">
        <div class="container container--flex">
        <span class="icon-btnmenu" id="btnmenu"></span>
        <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                        <div class="container-fluid navbar.fixed-top">
                <div class="row flex-items-xs-between menu-1flex-items-xs-middle"
                >
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <a data-scroll href="#sec-1" class="menu__link" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Inicio</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <li class="menu__item"><a href="nosotros.html" class="menu__link menu__link--select">Nostros</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="Mapa.html" class="menu__link menu__link--select">Visitanos</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="galeria.html" class="menu__link menu__link--select">Galería</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="inicio.html" class="menu__link menu__link--select">Registrar Datos</a></li>


        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CODIGO CSS

```
.icon-btnmenu {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    border: 0;

}
.menu {

    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .12s linear;

}
.icon-btnmenu:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1)
}
.menu__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu__link:hover {
    background: #DE423A;
}
.menu__link--select {
    bakcground: #DE423A;

}
.mostrar {
    height: 237px;
}
```

CODIGO JAVA SCRIPT

```
let btnMenu = document.getElementById('btnmenu');
let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
btnMenu.onmouseover(function){
    'use strict';
    menu.classList.toggle('mostrar')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice unos cambios a tu código. 
Primero en el html tienes un `<div>` dentro de una lista `<ul>`. Lo he cambiado con un `<li>`.

En el javascript utilizo `btnMenu.addEventListener`

Espero que esto sea lo que preguntabas.

```js
let btnMenu = document.getElementById('btnmenu');
let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
btnMenu.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
    'use strict';
    menu.classList.toggle('mostrar')
});
```

```css
.icon-btnmenu {
  background:black;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    border: 0;

}
.menu {

    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .12s linear;

}
.icon-btnmenu:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1)
}
.menu__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu__link:hover {
    background: #DE423A;
}
.menu__link--select {
    background: #DE423A;

}
.mostrar {
    height: 237px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
        <div class="container container--flex">
        <span class="icon-btnmenu" id="btnmenu"></span>
        <ul class="menu" id="menu">
            <li class="container-fluid navbar.fixed-top">
            <div class="row flex-items-xs-between menu-1flex-items-xs-middle">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
               <a data-scroll href="#sec-1" class="menu__link" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Inicio</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li class="menu__item"><a href="nosotros.html" class="menu__link menu__link--select">Nostros</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="Mapa.html" class="menu__link menu__link--select">Visitanos</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="galeria.html" class="menu__link menu__link--select">Galería</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="inicio.html" class="menu__link menu__link--select">Registrar Datos</a></li>


        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, justo eso buscaba <3

Answer (score 1):

Explicación y muchos ejemplos **[AQUI](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)** ( w3schools )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lichtenstein_img_processing_test.png" width="32" height="32">

<script>
function bigImg(x) {
  x.style.height = "120px";
  x.style.width = "120px";
}

function normalImg(x) {
  x.style.height = "32px";
  x.style.width = "32px";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Happy coding !!!